High load ramp up within ms using jmeter tool
Is there any way to ramp up more than 7k tps in ms using jmeter tool?
I tried it out by setting ramp up as 0 but still taking more than a minute to ramp up targeted load
And also I have used ultimate thread group, virtual thread group , concurrency thread group

In any case JMeter will need some time to kick off 7000 threads, the exact time depends on your hardware, your OS configuration and your JMeter configuration.

Make sure to follow JMeter Best Practices
Make sure to follow recommendations 9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure article
Tune JVM and OS according to the nature of your test plan

If it's not enough there are following workarounds:

Use Synchronizing Timer before 1st Sampler and set the Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by to be equal to the number of threads in your Thread Group. This way JMeter will start executing the first Sampler only when 7000 threads will be available
Measure how many users you can kick off in 1 second (or whatever is the acceptable time), get the relevant amount of load generator machines and run JMeter in Distributed Mode

